# No deprecated_block_helpers in Rails 3.0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment

When I'm trying to launch my production server on Rails 3.0.5, I keep getting this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:70:in `const_get': no such file to load -- action_view/helpers/deprecated_block_helpers (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:70:in `local_constants'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:70:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:70:in `local_constants'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:68:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:68:in `local_constants'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:86:in `local_constant_names'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:100:in `new_constants'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:91:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:91:in `new_constants'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:599:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /home/punkweek/punkweek/config.ru:3
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /home/punkweek/punkweek/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/punkweek/punkweek/config.ru:1
```

It seems there's a problem with a file, deprecated_block_helpers, which is not found in Rails. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is a bug in Rails 3.0.5 (it has been fixed in edge).

DeprecatedBlockHelpers is autoloaded in ActionView::Helpers, but the file itself was removed in [9de8305](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9de8305)

This helper was designed to show a deprecation notice for using `<% %>` instead of `<%= %>` (or `-` instead of `=` in haml) for certain blocks.  I'm not sure exactly which blocks the deprecation is for, but maybe take a look through your templates and see if you can trial-and-error this into working.

Alternatively, you can vendor Rails and remove the DeprecatedBlockHelpers autoload, or track edge Rails.

Comment: I'll try to correct all the code that may cause that deprecation then.